# Composing a Buffy buffer from the middle of an array and finding out how much it has consumed

Tags: clojure, stream, netty, buffy

I'd like to use [Buffy](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy) to interpret binary data starting from the middle of an array. I also need to find out how many bytes of the array have been consumed by Buffy.

Let's say I have a dynamic buffer definition like this:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [read])
  (:use [byte-streams])
  (:require [clojurewerkz.buffy.core :refer :all]
            [clojurewerkz.buffy.frames :refer :all]
            [clojurewerkz.buffy.types.protocols :refer :all])
  (:import [io.netty.buffer Unpooled ByteBuf]))

(def dynbuf
  (let [string-encoder (frame-encoder [value]
                                      length (short-type) (count value)
                                      string (string-type (count value)) value)
        string-decoder (frame-decoder [buffer offset]
                                      length (short-type)
                                      string (string-type (read length buffer offset)))]
    (dynamic-buffer (frame-type string-encoder string-decoder second))))
```

I hoped I could use a [Netty `ByteBuf`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html) to parse a bunch of bytes using `dynbuf` starting at an offset:

```
(def buf
  (let [bytes (concat [0 0 0 4] (map #(byte %) "Foobar"))
        offset 2]
    (Unpooled/wrappedBuffer (byte-array bytes) offset (- (count bytes) offset))))
```

At this point, I can parse `buf` per `dynbuf`:

```
user> (decompose dynbuf buf)
["Foob"]
```

At this point, I was hoping that reading the `short-type` and the `string-type` from `buf` has moved its `readerIndex` by 6, but alas, it is not so:

```
user> (.readerIndex buf)
0
```

Is this because `buffy/decompose` makes some kind of shallow copy of the stream for its internal use, so the `readerIndex` of the outer `buf` is not updated? Or am I misunderstanding what `readerIndex` is supposed to be?

How can I achieve my original goal of passing a `(byte-array)` at a given offset to Buffy and learning how many bytes it has consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffy [is using](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy/blob/4ad7cfc36be9df55e87ae9d1e29685fc98d7d5dd/src/clojurewerkz/buffy/types.clj#L31) the [absolute version](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#getInt(int)) of the getXXX method, which do not modify the position of the buffer, so you cannot use .readerIndex.

I see two possible options, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

1. Use Buffy [dynamic frames](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy#dynamic-frames). Note that the `clojurewerkz.buffy.frames` namespace has a [`decoding-size`](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy/blob/4ad7cfc36be9df55e87ae9d1e29685fc98d7d5dd/src/clojurewerkz/buffy/frames.clj#L67) function if you want to know how much the dynamic frame will take. Something like:

   ```
   (defn read-from-middle [data f-type start-idx]
     (let [tmp-buf (Unpooled/wrappedBuffer data start-idx (- (alength data) start-idx))
           buffy-buffer (dynamic-buffer f-type)
           total-size (decoding-size f-type tmp-buf 0)]
       [(decompose buffy-buffer tmp-buf) (+ start-idx total-size)]))

   (def f-type
     (let [string-encoder (frame-encoder [value]
                                         length (short-type) (count value)
                                         string (string-type (count value)) value)
           string-decoder (frame-decoder [buffer offset]
                                         length (short-type)
                                         string (string-type (read length buffer offset)))]
       (frame-type string-encoder string-decoder second)))

   (let [my-data (byte-array [0 1 0x61 0 2 0x62 0x63 0 1 0x64])
         idx 0
         [i1 idx] (read-from-middle my-data f-type idx)
         [i2 idx] (read-from-middle my-data f-type idx)
         [i3 idx] (read-from-middle my-data f-type idx)]
     [i1 i2 i3])
   ```
2. Calculate the size of the frame [as Buffy is doing](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/buffy/blob/master/src/clojurewerkz/buffy/core.clj#L136) and manually set the correct position in the buffer. Something like:

   ```
   (import [io.netty.buffer Unpooled])
   (require '[clojurewerkz.buffy.core :as buffy]
            '[clojurewerkz.buffy.types.protocols :as ptypes])

   (defn read-from-middle [data spec start-idx]
     (let [total-size (reduce + (map ptypes/size (map second spec)))
           tmp-buf (Unpooled/wrappedBuffer data start-idx (- (alength data) start-idx))
           buffy-buffer (buffy/compose-buffer spec :orig-buffer tmp-buf)]
       [(buffy/decompose buffy-buffer) (+ start-idx total-size)]))

   (let [my-data (byte-array [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3])
         spec (buffy/spec :foo (buffy/int32-type))
         idx 0
         [i1 idx] (read-from-middle my-data spec idx)
         [i2 idx] (read-from-middle my-data spec idx)
         [i3 idx] (read-from-middle my-data spec idx)]
      [i1 i2 i3])
   ```